# network connection delegate for CoreData mapping with RestKit 0.20.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

When we do CoreData mapping with RestKit 0.20.2, there will be a network communication prior to mapping.
Can we set a delegate here to get response before mapping? I want to check some strings in the response and to decide whether i want to go for mapping. Can we prevent mapping after response? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a complete mapping, you could define an `RKDynamicMapping` which will allow you to interrogate the parsed data before it is mapped and decide what to do (which mapping to apply to it). If the dynamic mapping returns nil then no mapping will be performed. This approach is simpler than trying to insert yourself as a delegate into the process.